# How to insert a string with ' and " in sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to insert a string with both ' and " into the database. I know how to handle one, but what to do when both are present, can I use escape characters?

Comment: Show us an example of how you are “inserting a string” into the database.

Comment: Either use parametrized queries, or escape the quotes.

Comment: What application language are you using?

Comment: Use `\'`, it's that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your database software (MySQL? Oracle?)

In mysql, you escape single quote with a backslash:

```
\'
```

In oracle you use a double quote:

```
''
```

(this is 2 single quotes).

There is no need to escape `"`.

Also as an added bonus, you should not be doing this. Use at least "parametrized queries" or a ORM (object relation mapping) framework.

Comment: He doesn't need an ORM framework, PDO is fair enough.

Comment: We have not determined that this person is using PHP or even any of its supported relational database software. However it does seem likely that this is PHP MySQL :)